# If cell is blank preform formula else use value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to conditionally set the value of a cell if there isn't already a value in it. I want to use a separate column so as to not lose the formula if a value is put in. This is what I'm trying. It's just saying FALSE in the cell

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),D2=FILTER(Characters!G3:G9,Characters!B3:B9 = B2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove D2=

```
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),FILTER(Characters!G3:G9,Characters!B3:B9 = B2))
```

Comment: This formula is in E2 so if a value is input in D2 then removed D2 can still default to some value

Comment: Then you want to be checking if E2 is blank from your other cell.

Comment: Re-read your question. I see what you're trying to do now. I have tended to use scripting once you get to this level. The builtins don't deal with checking if something already has a value in it AFAIK.

Comment: I switched were I was checking for isblank and that worked thanks

Comment: I considered using scripting but I wanted to keep it simple